The SSL connection could not be established - Azure AKS
My application hosted in Azure AKS, My app got logic to call some external API frequently.
In my local I don't face any issue to call the external API,
but, Getting below error while call api from inside Azure AKS
https:///connect/token
The SSL connection could not be established
Based on some suggestion, I added below piece of code, but not working.
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
_client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);


have you tried to ping whatever you want to access from the pods (or whatever the container called as)? make sure they can actually talk with anything outside. this documentation might be helpful.
